# Grails ASTTransformation: how to load other class (e.g. Class.forName(..))?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, classloader, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing an `ASTTransformation` (in JAVA) in my `Grails`-project.

Because I want to **transform the annotated class based on another class**, I need to load the other class and also analyze it's `AST`.

But I have no success with loading the other class:

```
Class.forName("OtherClass") -> ClassNotFoundException
Class.forName("OtherClass", false, classNode.getClassLoader()) -> ClassNotFoundException
OtherClass.class -> ClassNotFoundException
```

It think because the `AST` is per se executed at compile-time, the other class is just not available yet.

Maybe it is possible to get the source of the other class in my `ASTTransformation` and then build the `AST` of it with

```
new AstBuilder().buildFromCode { ... }
```

or something like that.

But how to load the resource/code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution now:

```
ClassNode classNode = (ClassNode) astNode;
classNode.getCompileUnit().getClass("de.foo.bar.OtherClass")
```

creates a new `ClassNode` with all informations about fields, methods, properties and so on.